# I didnt insert my userid or password and when I click login button it forced closed my application

Tags: android, json

This is my logcat

```
12-08 16:21:34.229: D/request!(7364): starting
12-08 16:21:34.499: D/Login attempt(7364): {"message":"Please fill in the login details!"}
12-08 16:21:34.499: W/System.err(7364): org.json.JSONException: No value for success
12-08 16:21:34.509: W/System.err(7364):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
12-08 16:21:34.509: W/System.err(7364):     at org.json.JSONObject.getInt(JSONObject.java:443)
12-08 16:21:34.509: W/System.err(7364):     at com.pmss.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:146)
12-08 16:21:34.509: W/System.err(7364):     at com.pmss.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
12-08 16:21:34.509: W/System.err(7364):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-08 16:21:34.509: W/System.err(7364):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
12-08 16:21:34.509: W/System.err(7364):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-08 16:21:34.509: W/System.err(7364):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-08 16:21:34.509: W/System.err(7364):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-08 16:21:34.509: W/System.err(7364):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-08 16:21:34.519: D/AndroidRuntime(7364): Shutting down VM
12-08 16:21:34.519: W/dalvikvm(7364): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
12-08 16:21:34.529: E/AndroidRuntime(7364): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 16:21:34.529: E/AndroidRuntime(7364): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 16:21:34.529: E/AndroidRuntime(7364):     at com.pmss.Login$AttemptLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:162)
12-08 16:21:34.529: E/AndroidRuntime(7364):     at com.pmss.Login$AttemptLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:1)
12-08 16:21:34.529: E/AndroidRuntime(7364):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
12-08 16:21:34.529: E/AndroidRuntime(7364):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
12-08 16:21:34.529: E/AndroidRuntime(7364):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
12-08 16:21:34.529: E/AndroidRuntime(7364):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-08 16:21:34.529: E/AndroidRuntime(7364):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-08 16:21:34.529: E/AndroidRuntime(7364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-08 16:21:34.529: E/AndroidRuntime(7364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 16:21:34.529: E/AndroidRuntime(7364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-08 16:21:34.529: E/AndroidRuntime(7364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-08 16:21:34.529: E/AndroidRuntime(7364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-08 16:21:34.529: E/AndroidRuntime(7364):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my Login.java

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener  {

private Button login,register;
private EditText email,password;
// Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String LOGIN_URL =         "http://192.168.1.14:1234/PMSS/login.php";      
  //JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerlauncher);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userid);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Username = email.getText().toString();
            String Password = password.getText().toString();
            new AttemptLogin(Username,Password).execute();
        }
    });

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // For the main activity, make sure the app icon in the action bar
        // does not behave as a button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    /*case R.id.login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        break;
    case R.id.register:
            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
        break;
*/
    default:
        break;
    }
}

//AsyncTask is a seperate thread than the thread that runs the GUI
    //Any type of networking should be done with asynctask.
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
    //three methods get called, first preExecture, then do in background, and once do
    //in back ground is completed, the onPost execture method will be called.
        boolean failure = false;
   String res;
   String Username; 
   String Password;
   int success;
   public AttemptLogin(String Username, String Password) {
            this.Username = Username;
            this.Password = Password;
   }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
            System.out.print("Here");
            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            res = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            return success;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer success) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", res);
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", res);
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

    }
}
}
```

line 146: `success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);`

line 162: `if (success == 1) {`

If need provide anything else, do please mention it.
Is it where I write wrongly or I make some silly mistake. I will be appreciate of what you all tell me... Please help me out here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the `JSONException`, you return `null` for the `success` value. That's the reason for the FC. Just handle this case as not successful like this:

```
if (success != null && success == 1) {
    Log.d("Login Successful!", "res: " + res);
    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainMenu.class);
    startActivity(i);
    Toast.makeText(Login.this, res == null? "null" : res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Log.d("Login Failure!", "res: " + res);
    Toast.makeText(Login.this, res == null? "null" : res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

--- EDIT ---

A different approach is returning a valid int no matter what:

```
    // ...
    // json success tag
    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
    res = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "JSON error" ,e);
    success = Integer.valueOf(0);
    res = "unknown error";
}
return success;
```

Comment: Sure it's the very same error? The first part is only because you print out the stack trace, but the FC caused by the NPE should be gone.

Comment: I just changed the answer to catch some other potential NPEs.

Comment: Erm now it's different error which is the logcat `12-08 16:55:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8335):  at com.pmss.Login$AttemptLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:170)` and line 170 is `Log.d("Login Failure!", res);`

Comment: wow it works succesfully, but the ` "res: " + res` and `res == null? "null" : res,` means?

Comment: The `Log.e(TAG, "JSON error" ,e);` I have errors on the TAG, should I declare the 'TAG' as constant?

Comment: Sure, that's a common pattern to use a constant tag.

Comment: and after i change the TAG to constant, there's an error said `Interger cannot be resolved` in the line of `success = Interger.valueOf(0);`

Comment: Because there is a typo. You definitely should be able to find it yourself.